# Mirror GitHub repository to GitLab repository that is behind a VPN

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a GitLab repository (let's call it userrepo1) which is on a custom domain (let's call it test-users-projects.co.uk) which is accessible only through a VPN - so the full address of the repository would be https://test-users-projects.co.uk/username/userrepo1.git.

I also have a GitHub account which is not behind the VPN with a repository of the same name - userrepo1. The full address of which will be https://github.com/username/userrepo1.git. Due to the nature of the work that the user of the GitHub repository will be doing they will be connected to the VPN, but will not have access to the GitLab domain.

I wish to mirror the GitHub repository over to the GitLab repository whenever the user commits to the GitHub repository. I have tried various solutions using existing GitHub Actions such as those listed here https://github.com/marketplace?query=gitlab&type=actions, however I always encounter an error such as:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://test-users-projects.co.uk/username/userrepo1/': Could not resolve host: test-users-projects.co.uk

I have also tried Actions which rely on SSH, those return the following

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname test-users-projects.co.uk: Name does not resolve

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or opinions would be very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a self-hosted runner on your side if the VPN, as long as it can reach both the git lab and github it will be able to trigger when needed.

The self hosted runner connects outbound to GitHub so you wouldn't need GitHub to reach into your network. If the self hosted runner is running on your infra it is more likely to be able to connect to systems without a publicly addressable name.

See

- https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners

Or you will need to install the required VPN software and connect the agent from your workflow. If that's possible.

The whole reason you have a VPN is to protect the host from outside connections.